# Load Symfony asset from public_html/plugins folder

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic, symfony-2.8

**Symfony2.8** loads assets form **public_html/plugins** folder, but throws error when uploaded to main/production server.

***My folder structure,***

[image]

***In my main/production server throws error,***
[image]

I don't know what to do, to solve this error...

***My config file..***

[image]

***PHP Code used for asset,***

```
<script src="{{asset('plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
        {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
            {% if is_granted('ROLE_FZ_ADMIN') %}
                <script src="{{asset('plugins/ckeditor/config/fz.js')}}"></script>
            {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') %}
                <script src="{{asset('plugins/ckeditor/config/super.js')}}"></script>
            {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                <script src="{{asset('plugins/ckeditor/config/admin.js')}}"></script>
            {% else %}
                <script src="{{asset('plugins/ckeditor/config/user.js')}}"></script>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: did you do your `assets:install`? do you have any custom  `.htaccess`? you are showing us the folder structure from your prod environnement?

Comment: Thankyou, I removed .htaccess then there is no plugins folder in browser. Then changed folder permission. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** This file permission error. Changed all files and folder to 777. Problem solved.

```
chmod 777 -R project_location
```